# Cannot route with logic to my Views from Backbone Router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I try to make my router decide to show a login only home view, otherwise the login view or registerview.

my app is at initially localhost:8080/indexapp.

I load it at the data-main file. but the route tied to action that makes this decision is not triggered I think.

Is it possible to have a router with a route to be triggered on the page loaded.

Also, I have a commented one line that says `this.loginModel.fetch();` which causes undefined is not a function error.

```
    define([
    'jquery',
    'ratchet',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',

    'login/loginview',
    'login/loginmodel',
    'register/registerview',

    'home/homeview',
    ],
    function($, Ratchet, _, Backbone, LoginModel, LoginView, RegisterView, HomeView){
        var MainRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes: {
                "": "showHome",
                //"/": "showHome",

                "login": "showLogin",
                "register": "showRegister"
            },
            initialize: function(){
                Backbone.history.navigate("home", {trigger:true})
            },
            showHome: function(){
                //var self = this, loginModel = new LoginModel();
                this.loginModel = new LoginModel();
                //this.loginModel.fetch();

                if(this.loginModel.get('loginp') == true ){
                    this.homeView = new HomeView();
                    this.homeView.render();
                }
                else {
                    Backbone.history.navigate("/login", {trigger:true})
                }
                /*
                this.loginModel.fetch({
                    success: function(model){
                        if( model.get('loginp') == true ){ //show you app view for logged in users!
                            this.homeView = new HomeView();
                            this.homeView.render();
                        }
                        else { //not logged in!
                            Backbone.history.navigate("/login", {trigger:true})
                        }
                    },
                });
                */
            },
            showLogin: function(){ //display your login view
                this.loginView = new LoginView;
                //this.loginView.fetch();
                this.loginView.render();

            },
            showRegister: function(){ //display your register view
                this.registerView = new RegisterView;
                //this.registerView.fetch();

                this.registerView.render();
            },
        });

        return MainRouter;
});
```

loginmodel:

```
    define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    ],
    function(_, Backbone) {
        var LoginModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

            urlRoot: '/login',
            initialize: function(){
                this.fetch();
            },
            defaults: {
                username: null,
            },

        });

        return LoginModel;
});
```

loginview:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ratchet',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',

    'login/loginmodel',
    'text!login/logintemplate.html',

    ],
    function($, Ratchet, _, Backbone, LoginModel, LoginTemplate){
        var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({

            el: $('body'),

            model: new LoginModel,
            /*
            initialize: function(){
                this.model = new LoginModel;
            },
            */
            template: _.template( LoginTemplate ),

            render: function(){ //display your login view
                this.$el.html( template( this.model.attributes ) );
            },

        });

        return LoginView;
});
```

Comment: above question is mine and I am considering deleting it. Because the issue is originated from the wrong order of the dependenceis of the loginview. Should I delete it? Or answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to see you're following my idea! ;)

The only thing you're missing is to start up routing using Backbone.history.start() on $(document).ready.

http://backbonejs.org/#Router

It works this way: you need to instantiate your router(s) before calling Backbone.history.start().

So in your main app file, require your MainRouter, create one instance and start history.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  new MainRouter();
  Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Comment: thanks Charlie :) I will follow it and this answer of you reminded me I have already tested your code with my wraps and it works so I should tick your answer. Now I do starting it in my toplevelfile, my data-main.
`require(['main/mainrouter'], function(MainRouter){
 var mainRouter = new MainRouter;
 Backbone.history.start();
});`
However I started history it did not work. problem was the wrong dependency loading in the loginview file. Should I delete this question.

Comment: Yes but wrap in the $document.ready just in case anything has not finished loading yet!

Comment: Is it possible to wrap in require():
`require(['main/mainrouter'], function(MainRouter){
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var mainRouter = new MainRouter;
  Backbone.history.start();
 });
});`